# CSS - Sidebar items not aligning to left

Tags: html, css

I've recently had this problem.

I got a sidebar, but when the items (`li`) should be `left: 0` there's a gap of 20px.
I've tried almost everything to align it to the left.

I've marked the extra space with red.

If I make it `absolute`, it dissapears.
[image: The problem]

**Code**:

```
#navigation {
font-family: Source Sans Pro, Century Gothic;
font-size: 150%;
cursor: default;
color: #ba4d4d;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#navigation li {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 10px 0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px #E3E3E3 solid;
}

#navigation li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
text-align: left;
}

.side-nav {
width: 15%;
left: 0;
top: 100%;
background-color: #3c3c3c;
float: left;
height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="side-nav">

    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>
            <a href="#etusivu">ETUSIVU</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#tietoa">TIETOA MEISTÄ</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#yhteys">YHTEYSTIEDOT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Is there any padding-left for `ul id="navigation"` in the inspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to try this:

```
#navigation{
  padding:0;
}
```

As `ul`s leave default `20px` margins

### [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/jikejusi/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because UL has a default padding applied by UA.

Force padding to 0, like you made for others tag (i.e. LI)

```
#navigation
{
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first remove padding from ul

```
ul{
padding:0;
}
```

after that give some padding from left to li

```
#navigation li{
padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to add the padding back?

Comment: @claudio : This was only in the case if you need some space to left of li's for some bullets or icons etc. I should have mention that :)

Comment: Right, but not what I was looking for :)